# Eclipse: Java was started but returned exit code -1073741571

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

Eclipse is closing while loading any XML layout with this message `Java was started but returned exit code -1073741571`

***my eclipse.ini***

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss1024k
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.0-519525
```

[image]

Comment: There are at least 3 question with "Java was started but returned exit code" at SO. None of them help?

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov: trust me I am not new here

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Unless the exit code was the same I don't see them being very helpful to the OP. This http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838501 might be useful.

Comment: @NominSim: do you suspect issue in my windows? solution? it's seems something in the registry keys

Comment: @AhmadTK It definitely seems to be the registry keys, but I am not sure how Eclipse manipulates those at its level, or even whether it does. It very well could be something with your current workspace of Eclipse if that is the case, does the application fail if you start in a different workspace?

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem is not just with Eclipse but with Eclipse and the Android Developer Tools (ADT). Did you download the ADK Bundle (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or installed the Eclipse Android plugin into your existing Eclipse install?

Comment: What is the Java version/platform located in C:\Windows\System32? Does it match your Eclipse/ADT version?

Comment: @NominSim: I have not tried that yet, I will create new workspace and let you know.

Comment: @J. Gonzalez: yes I am using the ADK Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for sharing solutions with me it seem that I had corrupted xml ( I am still not sure what corrupted  means but it was forcing the IDE to crash) here is a snippet:

```
<com.android.example.EndlesScrollView...

    <FrameLayout...
        <LinearLayout...
```

Each time I tried to use `Graphical layout` view in eclipse the IDE crashes, All I did was to delete that XML totally and re-create it from scratch, it seems something wrong with the XML Tags which preventing the `Graphical layout` from correctly displaying the correct UI.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that the VM listed is: C:\Windows32\System\javaw.exe which I believe is the Java 7 installed version. My configuration is using one of the earlier installed JVMs (from my Eclipse.ini):

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

Maybe you should update Eclipse to use a 1.6 version of Java to run.  From the Eclipse readme.html (found in the Eclipse install directory):

> ```
> Specifying the Java virtual machine
> ```
>
> Here is a typical Eclipse command line:
>
> ```
> eclipse -vm c:\jdk1.4.2\jre\bin\javaw
> ```
>
> Tip: It's generally a good idea to explicitly specify which Java VM to
>   use when running Eclipse. This is achieved with the "-vm" command line
>   argument as illustrated above. If you don't use "-vm", Eclipse will
>   look on the O/S path. When you install other Java-based products, they
>   may change your path and could result in a different Java VM being
>   used when you next launch Eclipse.

Comment: thanks you very much for sharing this, I am testing this ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes means that the workspace is corrupted.

Create a fresh workspace and try a XML file.

Comment: I am testing this and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did to overcome is very simple. I just downloaded a JRE and put it in to the root folder of eclipse since eclipse by default looks for the jre in that location.
That's it....