# eclipse installed but cannot start java returned exit-code = 1

Tags: java, eclipse, exit-code

I recently installed eclipse-dsl-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64 and after extracting the files, as I started running Eclipse it gave me the following error :

> Java was started but returned exit code=1 (required java version=1.5)

I checked the reason for this and also tried reinstalling as well as solutions suggested by other discussion forums, but to no avail.

I have installed

- Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers : eclipse-dsl-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64 under the Eclipse Juno SR1 packages    AND
- JDK 1.7.0_11 (x64)

I have linked my Environment Variables up correctly and tried to compile a Java file through cmd and have succeeded.

I tried running the following in cmd: `-vm "mypath\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\bin"` command as forums suggested

as well as other paths `-vm "mypath\jdk1.7.0_11\bin" -vm "mypath\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\bin\javaw.exe"` even `-vm "mypath\jre6\bin"` out of desperation to no avail.

Please help me out with this. I'm stuck :(

Comment: What is your jre version? Do you have a 64bit jre?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling a your JDK

Comment: yes! i have a 64 bit jre.

Comment: `java -version` from the command line says?

Comment: Please post your eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to set -vm to point to jvm.dll instead of java.exe or javaw.exe

-vm C:your_java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll

It seems a bug with Java 1.7. If you go back to Java 1.6 the problem seems to disappear as well.

[Eclipse: Java was started but returned exit code -1073741571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022257/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1073741571)

Comment: For me, it was bin\server\jvm.dll, but this fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - a bit too much for a comment - my suggestion:

First of all: I've just tried it with - well - almost the configuration you have (Win8-64bit), but with already a newer java and the SR2 release of Eclipse-DSL. No issues. But I don't think the previous release could be the issue here, but if nothing helps: try downloading the SR2-release.

I know it's all stated in your post, but really make sure you're starting your 64-Bit eclipse with a 64-bit java. Also you always have to provide one of the java.exe, javaw.exe or jvm.dll in the vm-argument, if you provide the vm-argument - not just the java directory.

Also try the following: start with

```
-vm "<yourjavainstallation>\bin\java.exe" -consoleLog -debug
```

mind: it is `java.exe`, not javaw.exe - a console (command window) will appear - maybe the messages will help?

If all fails - try to do it with a 32-bit java and 32-bit eclipse installation. You can use the newest java - JDK 1.6 is not needed. One last point: the `required java version=1.5)` suggests you have an ancient JDK on your system (if the error message is correct that is). If you still have a JDK 1.4 and older on your system - try to deinstall it, if you really do not need it any more (I wouldn't find a reason what for actually).

One last thing: There is a way to make sure eclipse uses a specified jre without the vm-argument. You can actually copy the needed jre to your eclipse-installation in a sub-folder called "jre" resulting in the following structure:

```
eclipse
    eclipse.exe
    jre
       bin
          java.exe
          ...
       lib
          ...
```

and start the eclipse without the vm-argument. I hope one of the points will help!

Comment: Thank you so much. Installing a newer java has resolved my issue. Eclipse is now running smoothly on my system. Thanks a ton! again :)

Comment: +1 for *-consoleLog* !, very handy option (especially when the log file wasn't dumped due to the crash)

Comment: I copied the Jre from Java Home directory to eclipse directory and eclipse was able to detect the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

I have added following lines in eclipse.ini file after openFile.

-vm

C:/Progra~2/Java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin/javaw.exe

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a bug happens with JDK 1.7.0_11 (x64).
the Solution is in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14022587/2294985 , Illustrating what to change in the eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 1):

I started getting same error for eclipse after installing QTP on my laptop.

when I tried to run a simple java hello world program from command prompt , I got below error :

```
c:\Java\test>javac MyFirstApp.java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar;C:\Users\vivekrs\Documents\Raj\sev2\Tools\
QTP11\QuickTest\MSI\bin\java_shared\bin
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library jvmhook on the library path, with error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Then I removed JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTIONS variables from Environments and java and Eclipse both started working fine.

you can try type `javac` in cmd prompt and see what error you are getting, and try to resolve that error, elipse will start working.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed this line and works for me in Eclipse Luna:

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the line:
-XX:-UseCompressedOops

to eclipse.ini and so far so good!