# eclipse Windows 64 bit can't open

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I open Eclipsp.exe to run for android programming,this msg is appear 
what is the problem ?
note: I have downloaded jre from java website.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Java was started but returned exit code -1073741571](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022257/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1073741571)

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170776/eclipse-installed-but-cannot-start-java-returned-exit-code-1. If that doesn't work try adding -XX:-UseCompressedOops to your eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 1):

It's the path for your JDK and your environmental system variables. The environmental system variables for 64-bit Windows and JDK is different than 32-bit windows.

Also make sure you download 64-bit jre or jdk, then modify your eclipse.ini file and add:

```
-vm [fullpath of 64-bit jdk or jre]\javaw.exe
```

Comment: make sure you download 64-bit jre or jdk, then modify your eclipse.ini file and add: -vm [fullpath of 64-bit jdk or jre]\javaw.exe