# Getting "Java Result: -1073741571" on loading library Cryptopp

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native-code, crypto++

I'm trying to load custom c++ dll *(using jni)* to java, but i have a **problem:** my dll using cryptopp library, and when java tries to load depending *(including cryptopp)*, the application quits with the message:

> **Java Result:** -1073741571

What is that, can i fix this without removing cryptopp?

---

***Update:***

If i commented files zCypto.h and zCypro.cpp, and deleted all usage of cryptopp library, it works without any errors, error has thrown if i load cryptopp.
Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.loadLibrary("cryptopp");
    System.loadLibrary("ZCPP_Code64");
}
```

CPP Source (I make dll in Visual Studio 2012):

```
#include "zCrypto.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ru_zontwelg_Loader_loadCache 
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)
{

std::fstream stream;
stream.open("C:\\testing_capturing\\enc.zwac", ios_base::binary | ios_base::in);

// Other decode & read stuff here ...

stream.close();
}
```

Header:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class ru_zontwelg_Loader */

#ifndef _Included_ru_zontwelg_Loader
#define _Included_ru_zontwelg_Loader

extern "C" {

    /*
     * Class:     ru_zontwelg_Loader
     * Method:    loadCache
     * Signature: ()V
     */
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ru_zontwelg_Loader_loadCache
        (JNIEnv *, jobject);

}

#endif
```

zCrypto.h:

```
#ifndef ZontWelg_zCrypto
#define ZontWelg_zCrypto

#include <dll.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "cryptlib.h"
using CryptoPP::Exception;

#include "hex.h"
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

#include "base64.h"
using CryptoPP::Base64Encoder;
using CryptoPP::Base64Decoder;

#include "filters.h"
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter;

#include "sha.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "secblock.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "aes.h"
using CryptoPP::AES;

//#include "ccm.h"
using CryptoPP::CBC_Mode;

#pragma comment(lib, "cryptlib.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "cryptopp.lib")

using namespace std;

class zCrypto {
public:
    static string base64(string in);
    static string from_base64(string in);

    static string decrypt(const std::string& str_in);
};

#endif
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong, without seeing your code.  Can you try making the smallest possible program that exhibits this problem, and pasting it in here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Java was started but returned exit code -1073741571](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022257/eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1073741571). This can be tricky to search for because Google interprets the minus sign to mean "remove 1073741571 from results". Try this search: [Java "-1073741571"](https://www.google.com/#q=Java+Result%3A+%22-1073741571%22).

Comment: @Draiget - We need more details. Is this an Android/Ecplise project? Is this a Windows project (possibly from the potential duplicate). How much memory does the VM have? Did you use `javah` to generate the C/C++ headers from your Java class files? Are you calling into your DLL exclusively? Or are you calling the Crypto++ DLL on occasion?

Comment: @jww - I try to search error without "-", but could not find anything that referred to my problem. This is Java Application project in NetBeans (writed under Windows), and dll is c++ dynamic library (written in Visual Studio 2012). For generate headers i use `javah`

Answer (score 1):

This looks odd to me, but I'm not a JNI expert by any stretch:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.loadLibrary("cryptopp");
    System.loadLibrary("ZCPP_Code64");
}
```

I would expect to see something like (from one of my Crypto++/Android/JNI projects):

```java
public class PRNG {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("cryptopp");
        System.loadLibrary("prng");
    }

    private static native int CryptoPP_Reseed(byte[] bytes);

    private static native int CryptoPP_GetBytes(byte[] bytes);

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    // Returns the number of bytes consumed.
    public static int Reseed(byte[] seed) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_Reseed(seed);
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of bytes generated.
    public static int GetBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_GetBytes(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the `stlport_shared` because its an Android thing.

---

This also looks odd:

```cxx
#pragma comment(lib, "cryptlib.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "cryptopp.lib")
```

Because you are calling `System.loadLibrary("cryptopp")`, that means you are using the Crypto++ DLL. It also means this is not needed: `#pragma comment(lib, "cryptlib.lib")`. Pick static linking or dynamic linking, but not both.

It would probably be easiest if you (1) built your `ZCPP_Code64` DLL, and (2) statically linked to Crypto++. Then your static loader would look like:

```java
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ZCPP_Code64");
    }
```

---

*If* you choose static linking against Crypto++, then you will probably have to rebuild the static lib. That's because you'll end up in this configuration:

```
Your DLL -> dynamic linking against the C Runtime
Crypto++ LIB -> static linking against the C Runtime
```

That will cause a bunch of duplicate symbols (C Runtime symbols). What you want is:

```
Your DLL -> dynamic linking against the C Runtime
Crypto++ LIB -> dynamic linking against the C Runtime
```

To fix it, you open the Cryptlib project, and change the Runtime linking object from static to dynamic. See "Static Versus Dynamic Linking" at [Compiling and Integrating Crypto++ into the Microsoft Visual C++ Environment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16388/Compiling-and-Integrating-Crypto-into-the-Microsof).

---

This looks OK to me:

```java
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ru_zontwelg_Loader_loadCache 
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)
{
    ...
}
```

What I am not sure about... where native libraries need to be located on Windows. For that, take a look at [Java JNI and dependent libraries on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566732/java-jni-and-dependent-libraries-on-windows).

---

You are also going to have to perform locking *if* multiple threads access the same underlying Crypto++ object. In my case, the underlying object was an `AutoSeededRandomPool`:

```java
public class PRNG {

    ...

    // Returns the number of bytes consumed.
    public static int Reseed(byte[] seed) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_Reseed(seed);
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of bytes generated.
    public static int GetBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return CryptoPP_GetBytes(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

In you case, it might be a `Base64Encoder` or `Base64Decoder`.

Remember, all Crypto++ class objects are thread safe meaning they don't access global or shared data. But they are not safe when multiple threads (mis)use the same object.

---

The book I consult for JNI issues is [The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201325772).

---

Finally, sorry about the "answer". Its not really an answer. Rather, its a large comment that would not fit in a comment block.

Comment: Thanks for detailed post, but i getting error (`Java Result: -1073741571`) when java loading  compiled 64x crypto++ `System.load("<full path here>\\cryptopp.dll");` or `System.loadLibrary("cryptopp");`

Comment: @Draiget - Have you taken a look at [Java JNI and dependent libraries on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566732/java-jni-and-dependent-libraries-on-windows)?

Comment: This should work: `System.load("<full path here>\\cryptopp.dll")`. Are all components for the same platform? I.e., is Java 64-bit, is your DLL 64-bit, and is Crypto++ 64-bit?

Comment: I copied crypto++ in windows directory, I also look depending libraries in **Dependency Walker** and he using only `KERNEL32.dll` and `ADVAPI32.dll`. Yes, all libraries are 64-bit including JDK.